# Navigate to another variable page on specific event

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working on a live chat site for an event.

- There will be an audience watching a group of presenters in a live forum
- After the live forum, each of the presenters will go into "Breakout rooms"
- Some of the audience will want to go to breakout room 1, others into breakout room 2, etc

I'm trying to figure out how to let the people watching the forum choose which breakout session they want to watch in advance (ie, during the forum), then have the page automatically switch to the "breakout room" selected by the user once the leader of the breakout leaves the forum and room enters the breakout room.

Any suggestions?

Comment: too broad, guess it's not for SO

Answer (score 0):

Well, From what I understand you just need a Database.

During the forum, when the user chooses the breakout room 1 or 2, you may save this option in a database (even a temporary table).

After the live room, you check the option in DB and send the user to there.

If you aren't using a database, you can use a file or something like this. Actually, you may even use a session variable to store the user option.